# Function to find length of date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am using this function to get the diff of two dates a person with the date joined of =03/03/1993 and a date left date of 06/02/2012 should be bringing back 8yrs 11mths but in mine its bringing back 9 years 2 months also i need it adapted If year in Date Joined is after the Year in Date Left you need to minus one Year.  This is the same for months

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[hmsGetLosText]
        (@FromDt as datetime,@DateLeftOrg as Datetime) 
    returns varchar(255)
    as
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @yy AS SMALLINT, @mm AS INT, @dd AS INT,
                @getmm as INT, @getdd as INT, @Fvalue varchar(255)

      SET @DateLeftOrg = CASE WHEN @DateLeftOrg IS NULL THEN GetDate()
           WHEN @DateLeftOrg = '1/1/1900' THEN GetDate()
           ELSE @DateLeftOrg  
           END

    SET @DateLeftOrg = CASE WHEN YEAR(@FromDt) > YEAR(@DateLeftOrg) THEN DateAdd(yy, -1, @DateLeftOrg)
    else @DateLeftOrg 
     end 


        SET @yy = DATEDIFF(yy, @FromDt, @DateLeftOrg)
        SET @mm = DATEDIFF(mm, @FromDt, @DateLeftOrg)
        SET @dd = DATEDIFF(dd, @FromDt, @DateLeftOrg)
        SET @getmm = ABS(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt), @DateLeftOrg))
        SET @getdd = ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt), @DateLeftOrg), DATEADD(yy, @yy, @FromDt)), @DateLeftOrg))
        IF @getmm = 1
        set @getmm=0

        RETURN (
          Convert(varchar(10),@yy) + 'y ' + Convert(varchar(10),@getmm) + 'm ')
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I get your desired answer:

```
 DECLARE @D DATETIME
 SET @D  = CONVERT(datetime,'06/02/2002', 103)  - CONVERT(datetime,'03/03/1993', 103) 

 SELECT @D
 SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,@D) - 1900
 SELECT DATEPART(mm,@D) - 1
 SELECT DATEPART(day,@D) - 1
```

Comment: my converts are only there to match your data.

Comment: How would i incoperate that into the first code i posted that worked fantiastic

Comment: you are doing a lot of coding to get a date delta, you shouldn't need much code.  SQLSERVER does it for you implicitly.

Comment: its cause its a function can you re do it to return a string function then ?

Comment: can you please privde an example in use defined funciton plz @T McKeown 17 mins ago

Comment: you got it working with you udf?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the caller is somewhere converting the strings "03/03/1993" and "06/02/2012" to dates without being explicit about the date semantics and the months and days are getting swapped.

So "03/03/1993" is (coincidentally) unambiguous as "1993-MAR-03", but if "06/02/2012" is the same as "2012-FEB-06" then their difference is 8 years, 11 months.  But if "06/02/2012" is interpreted as "2012-JUN-02", then their difference is 9 years, 2 months.

To fix this, the caller should either use a less ambiguous format, such as "2012-02-06" (which is always Feb 6th) or explicitly qualify and cast it.  This is how you would do that in T-SQL:

```
SELECT @date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '06/02/2012', 103)
```

which is also always interpreted as Feb 6th.

Comment: date joined is stored in db as 1993-03-03 00:00:00.000 and date left is stored as 2002-02-06 00:00:00.000

Comment: @user3156467 Is it stored as a string?  That alone is a bug, dates and times should never be stored as string because it always causes havoc down the road (like this).

Comment: no its not stored as a string obv its date time stamp

Comment: @user3156467 there is no such datatype as "*date time stamp*".  Please be explicit.  If you are trying to say that it is stored as a `DATETIME` datatype (and that is not at all obvious), then somewhere along the way they are being converted to strings and then back into datetimes and the months and days are getting swapped.

Comment: can someone please provide an inline example of this in my code

Comment: @user3156467 As I said above, the problem is in the *calling code*, not in the code/function that you have shown us.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this to get the delta:

```
DECLARE @Delta DATETIME

SET @Delta = @End - @Start
```

So if you were expecting 8 years then the @Delta year would 1908, then you get the month of @Delta, the day, hour, min. etc....

Comment: Can you provide an inline example please first time using deltas

Comment: Can someone clairfy this please

Comment: go to mgmt studio and paste/run this:    SELECT GETDATE() - '2/8/1969'.  The result is a DATETIME but it is the delta (difference)  number of years, months, days, min, secs

Comment: that does not give me my answer i need to have 8 years and 11 months this is not doing what im looking for

Comment: wait... what are the 2 dates? 06/02/2012 and 03/03/1993 yes?

Comment: 03/03/1993 AND 06/02/2002

Comment: 03 being the start date end 06 being the dateleft orignization

Comment: fyi.. your question has a different dates, it has 6/2/2012... but regardless, paste this on mgmt studio:   SELECT  CAST('06/02/2002' AS DATETIME) - CAST('03/03/1993' AS DATETIME).  You get a datetime return of:  1909-04-02 00:00:00.000

Comment: that result of 9 years, 4 months, 2 days.....  why are you expecting any different?  This assumes the date format of MM/DD/YYYY what are you doing?  DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: This is not the problem.  The problem is that unqualified date-strings are interpreted differently depending on internationalization settings, etc., and depending on on whether they are converted on the client or the server.

Comment: ok. we can solve that....  these dates I assume are DD/MM/YYYY?  ok we just need to provide that info in the CONVERT.  Not sure you can use CAST... let me check.

Comment: As i said the values are the same the calling code is getting it from the employee table

SELECT  dbo.hmsGetLosText(e.date_joined,e.date_left)
  FROM [pamsv83x].[dbo].[employee] e 
  
  where staff_no ='M0064'

Comment: the calling code is reading it from the same table no convert done whatsoeevr 
SELECT  dbo.hmsGetLosText(e.date_joined,e.date_left)
  FROM [pamsv83x].[dbo].[employee] e 
  
  where staff_no ='M0064'